# Why is my listview not scrolling smoothly?

Tags: android, listview, view, scroll, layout-inflater

I am a nood to Android development and i am trying to populate a listview with an image an text parsed from twitter during OnCreate.  I can populate the listview without any problems but the listview scrolls jerky instead of smoothly.  At first i thought it was an emulator issue, but it scolls jerky on my device as well.  What makes it so frustrating is that I am using the viewholder approach that all the tutorials and posts on stackoverflow recommend.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is my code...

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
          ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();          
          holder.username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);        
          holder.message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
          holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
          v.setTag(holder);

    }

    Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
    if (tweet != null) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        holder.username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
        holder.message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
        holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

        if (holder.username != null) {
            holder.username.setText(tweet.username);
        }

        if(holder.message != null) {
            holder.message.setText(tweet.message);
        }

        if(holder.image != null) {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tweet.image_url));

        }
    }
    return v;
}
}

static class ViewHolder {
        TextView username;  
        TextView message;
        ImageView image;
    }

public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection() .getInputStream()); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {return null;}
}
```

Comment: Does getBitmap downloads the image over internet?

Comment: Can you post your code for getBitmap? Bitmap operations can be really slow and usually have to be done asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, check my edit. I added the method so you can look at it.

Comment: getBitmap is definately your problem, it is downloading and decoding your image in the UI thread. This will cause significant pauses in scrolling, and crash your app on android 4.0+

Comment: @Rob how would you recommend I fix the bitmap issue?

Comment: You are also not using ViewHolder correctly. The whole point of ViewHolder is so that you only have to run the findViewById calls the first time when you inflate, not subsequent times when you are reusing the passed in view to convert. You should remove the second set of three findViewById calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getBitmap method is downloading and decoding the image on the UI thread. This will cause significant pausing in scrolling and crashes on later versions of android.

The [Developer Guide on Bitmap Processing](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) contains a fairly easy to implement technique for loading bitmaps asynchronously